# Error with updating one table column with reference of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to update a column in a table with reference to other table. There are two tables, `nt_masterinstrument` and `SQLSymbol` (see Screen A).  The description in `nt_masterinstrument` is empty and I try to update it from `SQLSymbol`. The Screen B shows the update statement and error.  I am using MS SQL Compact Query Analyzer.

Image:

[image: Two Tables And Update Statement]

To put it simple: Two Tables, TblCust and TblTemp as below:

TblCust   CustCode      CustName

```
      T01
```

TblTemp   TempCode      TempName

```
      T01       Andy Skinner
```

Please help me to write an Update statement to update the CustName from TblTemp.

Comment: Please copy the SQL statements here. Your UPDATE statement is invalid. `FROM` clause should be removed and you should use a sub `SELECT` statement to get the value from `SQLSymbol` table

Comment: @Stanley the update statement syntax is fine in sql server and presumably postgre sql. Didn't look at anything else

Comment: Hi, I removed the from clause and use a sub select statement, but all not working as well.  It is just a simple update statement but I really don't know what is the problem (must be something very simple).  I found the standard update statement from this website: UPDATE A
    SET A.NAME = B.NAME
FROM TableNameA A, TableNameB B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID .  Could it be due to different standard in sql statement?  Please help!    Toyogo

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
update alias_tbl 
set alias_tbl.description=sqlsymbol.descrition
from nt_masterintrument alias_tbl  JOIN sqlsymbol
on nt_masterintrument.name=sqlsymbol.name
where /*filter condition*/
```

Comment: Hi, I've learned that SQL and SQL Compact has different syntax, (no from clause).  However, after reading the reference which only provide single table update statement.  I still need help from those programmers who are familiar with SQL Compact!  Rgs, Toyogo